# Updating the database withe the migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a simple user table and i would like to add a new field to my user table that says permalink. This permalink would be updated with the following code for all the users
`name.downcase.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]+/, ' ').strip.gsub(' ', '-')`. I want to create a migration file that updates all the users permalink fields with the code above so that old users would have their permalink set and i would use an after_create method for new users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :set_permalink

  def set_permalink
    permalink = name.downcase.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]+/, ' ').strip.gsub(' ', '-') 
  end
end
```

This actually uses the `before_create` callback, which would address the deriving of the `permalink` field for new users. I think this is what you actually need.

And in your migration file ...

```
class UpdateUsersPermalink < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    User.reset_column_information
    User.all.each do |u|
      if u.permalink.nil?
        u.set_permalink
        u.save!
      end
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

.. which would take care of any existing `User`s that do not have this field set just yet.

Comment: i would like the permalink of the users to be updated with the users names just like this `  def set_permalink
    self.permalink = name.downcase.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]+/, ' ').strip.gsub(' ', '-')
  end` this is possible using an after create method so i want to move it to the migration cos it would be a new update and so that all user can have a permalink not just new users

Comment: @UchennaOkafor thanks for the clarification, I updated the solution above. Have a look and see if this fits your needs.

Comment: just a little deep search and found this ` User.all.each { |f| f.update_attributes! :permalink => f.name.downcase.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]+/, ' ').strip.gsub(' ', '_') }
  ` it also works well

Comment: but yours a real saying of moving logic to models. Cool thanks bro

Comment: Uh, why aren't you using `parameterize` on the `f.name` object? That would do the gsubs and strips for you.